# check RDP login success with Powershell

Tags: powershell, rdp

Using Powershell I open some RDP sessions with this commands:

```
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$server /user:$user /pass:$serverPassword    
mstsc /v:$server /f
```

Works fine. But sometimes a session don't starts, e.g. because of server is unavailable or credentials are wrong.
What would be an easy way to check, whether the login was successful and RDP desktop is visible?

Comment: Just so you know, neither of those are actually Powershell commands.

Comment: Right, but if you search for "powershell rdp session", you will mostly get this commands. I use it within a much longer powershell script. So I don't need help for the mentioned commands, I look for a powershell solution to check afterwards.

Comment: You should always give as much information as possible.  It enables us to help you better.  If you post only excerpt you will get inferior answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this form it has nothing to do with powershell (those are plain executable files).  It could be run also as batch file (Both `cmdkey` and `mstsc` are executables and you don't have `.\` before them or starting them via `invoke-command` or other means).

I will use the variables from your code and powershell (I'm not adjusting it to run via `invoke-command` or others.  That is out of the scope of this question and would be good practice for you):

```
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$server /user:$user /pass:$serverPassword    
mstsc /v:$server /f
```

To check if the you have connected session in the [Windows Event logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-6) - via `Get-Winevent`:

```
Get-Winevent -comp $server -FilterHashtable @{Logname='security'; ID=4624; StartTime=(Get-Date).addMinutes(-10)} | where {$_.properties[8].value -eq 10 -and $_.properties[5].value -eq $user}
```

Description of the command (skipping the obvious):

- [`-FilterHashtable`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/06/03/use-filterhashtable-to-filter-event-log-with-powershell/)
- Logname='security' - it is the Windows Log group `Security` (you have
  `Application`, `Security`, `Setup`, `System` and `Forwarded events`
  in Windows 7)
- `ID=4624` - That is an `ID` of the security event `4624: An account was successfully logged on`
- `StartTime=(Get-Date).addMinutes(-10)}` subtracting 10 minutes from the current time (*note:* you should adjust this according to your needs)
- then further filtering with `|`
- `$_.properties[8].value -eq 10` RDP (alias RemoteInteractive) session is type 10.

Here is the type table:

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Logon Type      ║ Description                                                                 ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 2               ║ Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)                        ║
║ 3               ║ Network (i.e. connection to shared folder on this computer from elsewhere   ║ 
║                 ║ on network)                                                                 ║
║ 4               ║ Batch (i.e. scheduled task)                                                 ║
║ 5               ║ Service (Service startup)                                                   ║
║ 7               ║ Unlock (i.e. unnattended workstation with password protected screen saver)  ║
║ 8               ║ NetworkCleartext (Logon with credentials sent in the clear text. Most often ║
║                 ║ indicates a logon to IIS with "basic authentication")                       ║
║ 9               ║ NewCredentials such as with RunAs or mapping a network drive with alternate ║
║                 ║ credentials.  This logon type does not seem to show up in any events.  If   ║
║                 ║ you want to track users attempting to logon with alternate credentials see  ║
║                 ║ security Type ID 4648.  MS says "A caller cloned its current token and      ║
║                 ║ specified new credentials for outbound connections. The new logon session   ║
║                 ║ has the same local identity, but uses different credentials for other       ║
║                 ║ network connections."                                                       ║
║ 10              ║ RemoteInteractive (Terminal Services, Remote Desktop or Remote Assistance)  ║
║ 11              ║ CachedInteractive (logon with cached domain credentials such as when        ║
║                 ║ logging on to a laptop when away from the network)                          ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

- `-and $_.properties[5].value -eq $user` last but not the least, filtering based on the `$user` variable